# AWS athena giving error when trying to query files in S3 that have already been catalogued in Glue data catalog

Tags: amazon-s3, gzip, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

Trying to build a data lake using S3 for files that are in .csv.gz format and then further cleansing/processing data in AWS environment itself.
First used AWS Glue to create a data catalog\ (crawler was able to identify all tables).
The tables from catalog are also available in AWS Athena but when i try to run a Select * from the table it gives me following error.

*Error opening Hive split s3://BUCKET_NAME/HEADER FOLDER/FILENAME.csv.gz (offset=0, length=44354) using org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat: Permission denied on S3 path: 3://BUCKET_NAME/HEADER FOLDER/FILENAME.csv.gz*.

Could it be that the file is in CSV.GZ format and that is why it cannot be accessed as is or do i need to give user or role a specific access for these files?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your permissions. The error says the principal (user/role) that ran the query does not have permission to read an object on S3.